# I am unable to Download file using DownloadManger in Android 10?

Tags: android, path, android-download-manager

Recently I update my app to **`Android 10 / API 29`** now and I am unable to download Image file Using android default download manager and show following error.

```
>>>>>: java.lang.SecurityException: Unsupported path /storage/emulated/0/MyFolder/RPS_20200930_191705.png
```

**My code**

```
 private boolean downloadTask(String url) throws Exception {
        if (!url.startsWith("http")) {
            return false;
        }
        String name = new SimpleDateFormat("'RPS_'yyyyMMdd_HHmmss'.png'", Locale.ENGLISH).format(new Date());
        try {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyFolder");
            if (!file.exists()) {
                //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
                file.mkdirs();
            }
            File result = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + name);
            DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI); 
            request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(result)); 
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            if (downloadManager != null) {
                downloadManager.enqueue(request);
            }
            mToast(mContext, "Starting download...");
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(WebActivity.this, new String[]{result.toString()}, null,
                    new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        }
                    });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(">>>>>", e.toString());
            mToast(this, e.toString());
            return false;
        } 
        return true;
    }
```

Even I also added read/write permissions and LegacyExternalStorag manifiest.xml

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

**and usage**

```
downloadTask("https://linkpicture.com/Images/gplogo.png");
```

Comment: `file.mkdirs();` Check the return value and do not continue if it fails but display a toast to inform the user and return.

Comment: The download manager will not download to root of external storage. Use your own folder in one of the public dirs like Download, Documents, DCIM and so on. No need to create the folder yourself. Downloadmanager will do it.

Comment: still the same issue. its download view but not save in file manager/ gallery

Comment: It should save the file to indicated storage path. Where are you talking about?

Comment: I check it working on publicdirectory like download music pictures etc but not working custom directry, if you have any solution for customize directory?

Comment: `Use your own custom  folder in one of the public dirs like Download, Documents, DCIM and so on.`

Comment: Okay. after some research if we download the file to the internal folder of the app and then move to the custom folder.